# Authorize.net : An error occurred on the server

Tags: magento-2.1, authorize.net

Magento authorize.net configuration has test mode and debug enabled. Gateway url: https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

When we try to place an order with test credit card number 4111111111111111 we get an alert message:

> An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.

Initially we got infinite loader and also in the network tab, the error Message:

> Please enter a transaction ID to authorize this payment

and could see transact.dll as in the image [image]

But now only getting alert:

> An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again

Tried to display the exact error message by modifying `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php` to `output $e->getMessage()` instead of the generic display message. But it's still displaying the generic message.

How to fix this issue such that the order is placed in processed mode and customer is redirected to success page?

Comment: what is exact error?

Comment: That's what I am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

app\code\Magento\Payment\view\frontend\templates\transparent\iframe.phtml

```
 globalMessageList.addErrorMessage({
                    message: '<?php echo $params['error_msg'];?> Please double-check your billing details or call ### immediate assistance.'
                });
```

Add above the line on line 42 and check which error showing.

Comment: I made the change in vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/transparent/iframe.phtml and flushed the cache too. Still I'm getting the generic message - "An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again"

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php  check line no 366, so you need to add log 512 msg.

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you please tell me where I need to modify?

Comment: @Karts please check log file.https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Authorizenet/Controller/Directpost/Payment/Place.php

Comment: i dont have the /transparent folder ! where is it??

Comment: im on magento 2....this looks like magento 1 code

Comment: Check your theme file app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Payment/templates/transparent/iframe.phtml